# How to get index of selected option with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sorry for newbie question.
But how can i get an index of selected element from selectbox and run a function. My code below doesn't trigger switchView() function.

```
<select id="selectbox" @change="switchView(index)">
  <option [v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:value="item.title"]>
    {{ item.title }}
  </option>
</select>
```

any help will be appreciated.

**EDITED:**
moved `@change="switchView(index)"` from `<option>` to `<select>`, thanks to @Phil

I need index, because i have several calculated items. And i need change view according to user's selection from items.

Comment: The event is fired on the `<select>`, not the `<option>`. Why do you need to know the index though?

Comment: aah, thanks @Phil. Now I can trigger the function.
I need index, because i have several calculated items. And i need change view according to user's selection from items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `@change` on `select` element and get the index with help of [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) function. Here is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mw66akuc/).

See code:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        age: '',
        selectedIndex: '',
        options: [1,2,3,44,55]
      };
    },
    methods: {
      selected: function () {
         this.selectedIndex = this.options.indexOf(this.age)
         alert('this is selected Index ' + this.selectedIndex)
       }
    }   
})
```

Comment: `@click` does not work because `<option>` elements do not fire click events.

Comment: @tagaism point noted, my bad for not testing, see updated answer.

Comment: @jingman point noted, my bad for not testing, see updated answer.

Comment: Demo link is broken

Answer (score 20):

#### Pass `$event.target.selectedIndex` to your function

Use the `@change` directive to listen to the change event. Invoke your function and **pass** the `$event` or the selected index of the event target **`$event.target.selectedIndex` as a parameter to your function.**

```
<select @change="switchView($event, $event.target.selectedIndex)">
```

Your method receives the passed parameters.

```
  methods: {
    switchView: function(event, selectedIndex) {
      console.log(event, selectedIndex);
    }
  }
```

#### Full Example [https://jsfiddle.net/3p7rhjyw/](https://jsfiddle.net/tobiobeck/3p7rhjyw/)

```
<div id="app">
  <select @change="switchView($event, $event.target.selectedIndex)">
  <option v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:value="item.title">
    {{ item.title }}
  </option>
</select> 
<p>
{{ selectedIndex }} {{ items[selectedIndex].id }}
</p>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { title: "Learn JavaScript", id: 'A' },
      { title: "Learn Vue", id: 'B' },      
      { title: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: 'C' },
      { title: "Build something awesome", id: 'D' }
    ],
    selectedIndex: 0
  },
  methods: {
    switchView: function(event, selectedIndex) {
      console.log(event, selectedIndex);      
      this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Mozilla documentation about [HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex).

Comment: `selectedIndex` indeed is better solution for this situation, I believe this answer should be most upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

For an pre-modified bootstrap-vue, this event handling might be different from the **$event.target.selectedIndex**. Especially for Vue 3, this answer might save your time.

```
<b-form-select @change="onChange" :options="options"></b-form-select>
```

Method that receives event from the user selection.

```
  methods: {
    onChange: function(event) {
      let index = event.target.selectedIndex
    }
  }
```

Full Example might be as follows:

```
<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange">
  </select> 
  <p>Selected index: {{ selectedIndex }}</p>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      "option 1",
      "option 2",
      "option 3",
      "option 4"
    ],
    selectedIndex: 0
  },
  methods: {
     onChange: function(event) {
       let index = event.target.selectedIndex // this selectedIndex is from event.
       this.selectedIndex = index
     }
  }
});
</script>
```